# DryIoc - Resolving a dervied class when base class is registered with a key name

Tags: c#, dryioc

Trying to build support for DryIoc in Prism.Forms (https://github.com/joacar/Prism/tree/pr-517) and stumbled upon a scenarion I can't manage to work out how to do.

To make a long story short the issues boils down to this: When creating a new application in Prism.DryIoc.Forms one creates an application subclass of PrismApplicationBase and overrides certain methods, one of them is RegisterTypes.

When called the user can register a view for navigation

```
container.RegisterPageForNavigation<MockView>(); 
// Extension method implementation
public static void RegisterPageForNavigation<TPage>(this IContainer container) 
where TPage : Xamarin.Forms.Page
{
    container.Register<TPage>(typeof(TPage).FullName);
}
```

During navigation a class `DryIocPageNavigationService` gets involved and has one method to override `protected Page CreatePage(string name) { ... }`

Here comes the problem: At this time we only know to resolve an implementation of `Page` given 'name' using IContainer.

```
protected Page CreatePage(string name) 
{ 
    // Always returns null
    return _container.Resolve<Page>(name, IfUnresolved.DefaultOrNull);
}
```

However, if implementing the extension method in such a way

```
 public static void RegisterPageForNavigation<TPage>(this IContainer container)
 where TPage : Xamarin.Forms.Page, new()
 {
     container.Register<Page>(made: 
         Made.Of(() => new TPage()),serviceKey:typeof(TPage).FullName);
 }
```

the page gets resolved. This however limits the `TPage` to have default empty constructor (or do some clever/unwanted hacking)

Hmm do short story get quite long :)

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of Register use [RegisterMany](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/wiki/RegisterResolve#markdown-header-registermany):

```
Container.RegisterMany<TPage>(
     serviceKey: whatever);
```

This will register single factory with multiple service types provided by TPage: TPage itself, base Page class, and interfaces if any.

```
// works
Container.Resolve<Page>(
     serviceKey: whatever);
```

Comment: I was about to open a question about this, thank you!